# Rails 3 undefined method `model_name' for Array:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

answers_controller:

```
@questions = Question.order("qtype, position")
@ans = Answer.where(user_id = current_user.id)
@answers = @questions.map { |q| [q, @ans.find_by_question_id(q.id)] }
```

view:

```
<%= form_for @answers, :remote => true do |form| %>
```

Is the error because @answers is is mapped? Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:

Answer model:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :question
```

User model:

```
has_many :answers
```

Question model:

```
has_many :answers
```

UPDATE 2:
I copied and pasted the following into the controller.

```
@answers = current_user.answers.questions
```

I got the following:

```
undefined method `questions' for #<Class:0x1032d6d98>
```

I tried going adopting the second approach - User model:

```
has_many :answers, :through => :answers
```

controller:

```
@questions = current_user.questions
```

and got:

```
undefined method `questions' for #<User:0x103569ec0>
app/controllers/answers_controller.rb:18:in `index'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@answers = @questions.map { |q| [q, @ans.find_by_question_id(q.id)] }
```

This gives you an array of arrays which in turn contain the question and another array of all of the question's answers. Like this:

```
[[q1, [q1_answer1, q1_answer2]], [q2, [q2_answer1, q2_answer2,...]], ...]
```

So each of the answers are in an array that itself is 2 levels deep inside @answers.

As for your problem when you reference current_user.answers, you get back an array of answers.

Associations are for an instance of a class, not a collection of them.  That is, you can call answer.question to get the question associated with a given answer.  However, you can't just call answers.questions as above, because a)answers is an array, not an Answer instance, and b) the association is 'question', not 'questions'

If you're trying to get all questions for all answers, you need to some sort of operation on each answer, like this:

```
questions = current_user.answers.map{|answer| answer.question}
```

which will map each question for each answer into an array. Note that if a user has multiple answers for a question, that question will end up in the array multiple times. It can be deduped with the 'uniq' method.

Comment: Thanks, @DougR. Very helpful. The mapping i did in 3rd line of the post produces data that is accessed via an each do |q| loop with two tiers, e.g. q[0].question and q[1].score. Will your mapping produce a flat array? e.g. q.question and q.score? BTW, there is only 1 answer per question.

Comment: My mapping will produce a flat array of just questions. Basically what map does is create an array where each element is what is inside that block. If you want a nested array, where each element of the outer array is [q.question, q.score], you can do a further map on questions:  questions.map{|q| [q.question, q.score]}.  But since you already have that information in an array, I'm not sure why you need to do that.

Comment: you mentioned further map... you mean a map on the map or a more extensive map? Sorry, if you can give me an example... or point me to a resource that would help. update: i see more content in your comment. thanks.

Comment: getting a flat array would make updating answers easier... i think. The scope of this problem is so multifaceted that i tried to post it a piece at a time. That's not working. I think i've got to post the whole thing... tomorrow. Had enough of it today :=]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is the reason. You probably wanted to do:
    current_user.answers.questions

Which, if you have your associations set as needed, will return exactly what you want (by using joins behind the scenes)

update:

Now, by looking at your associations, I'm not sure, what you're trying to accomplish.
Won't @answers = current_user.answers return all answers, and then in the view you can use answer and corresponding question (and still use form_for @answers).
However if you want to have @questions instead, you can do something like this:

First, associate user with questions

```
class User
  has_many :questions, :through => :answers
end
```

The in your controller:

```
@questions = current_user.questions
```

Hope that it helps.

Comment: @Roman, the questions are ordered. They will not come out of the database in the same order as the answers. The questions and answers are mapped via the question_id field in the answers table. Added associations above. What i was trying to accomplish with mapping happens automatically?

Comment: @Roman, well... even tho it doesn't seem right, i'm going to try what you suggested here, then change the question order to see if this holds up.

Comment: @Roman, can you help me by telling me where i am to insert "current_user.answers.questions"? It is unclear to me how to apply your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Roman, now i understand. With the isight you've given me i'm going to create another post to address the underlying problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to list all answers, but in the same order as your questions.

I am assuming your models look like

```
class User
  has_many :questions, :through => :answers
  has_many :answers
end

class Question
  has_many :answers
  has_many :users, :through => :answers
end

class Answer
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question 
end
```

Getting the questions of the `current_user` should then just become:

```
@questions = current_user.questions.order("qtype, position")
```

getting the corresponding answers then becomes

```
@answers = @questions.map{|q| q.answer}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks. I am probably wrong, but my models don't look like what you describe. Can you explain something for me. My understanding is that Question has_many :answers. Even tho there is only one answer per user there would be many users so that each question would have as many answers as there are users. Am i looking at it the wrong way? Also, I don't understand a question belongs_to :user. Each question would belong to every user. Should i be looking at this from the standpoint of one user session or the whole database?

Comment: Nope, I was just assuming that. It was a guess. It is not a bad idea to make questions global, and users have answers to a specific question. I will adapt my answer to reflect that.